# Multi_query PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

```
function search_admin($q) {
    $db = load_db();
    $sql = "SELECT keyword FROM keyword WHERE keyword LIKE = '%{$q}%'";
    $sql .= " SELECT title, status
              FROM title
              WHERE CONCAT(title, ' ', status)
              LIKE '%{$q}%'";
    $sql .= " SELECT first_name, middle_name, last_name, cbemail
              FROM employees
              WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ' , middle_name, ' ' , last_name , ' ' , cbemail)
              LIKE '%{$q}%'";
    $sql .= " SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE = '%{$q}%'";

    $result = $db->multi_query($sql);

// missing code

}
```

I can't seem to understand the explanation in the php manual. I hope you can englighten me more. This is for a search bar, that if example he will search for "pending". The code will search on 3 tables which is the title, employees and users. Then output the results. Now my problem is what to do after i get the result query :/

Comment: [***manual***](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) suggests to use `mysqli_more_results()` with `mysqli_store_result()` in cycle.

Comment: Read this.. it will help you in this concept.. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: can u give me a sample code that will suit my code sir?.

Comment: Your multi query **will fail**. You need to separate each query with a semicolon.

Comment: There is a semi-colon. Or there is another semi-colon i should add?

Comment: Now you have php semicolons. But you should end each SQL statement with a semicolon in your `$sql` variable. Therefore starting with a second `select` change it to `$sql .= "; SELECT... `

Comment: "; SELECT title, status
   FROM title
   WHERE CONCAT(title, ' ', status)
   LIKE '%{$q}%'";

Like that?.